# IE css style differs 1px from chrome/firefox/opera

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, border

why IE always differ 1px from other browsers? please look at this picture, this is in firefox and opera and chrome

[image]

and it is in IE

[image]

as you can see IE moves the border 1px to left. it is not just in this case, I have seen this many times, why IE has such behavior ?

thanks

Comment: Without the source, especially the start of the HTML document, we can't fix your code. Please make a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/), possibly using http://jsfiddle.net